# how to bundle all php files together?

Tags: php, webpack

I have php application on localhost. I am using MySQL/apache xampp setup. I have multiple php file for basic CRUD operations .Also there are  multiple CSS and JavaScript utility files .I want to bundle all these files together and just have single entry point like ***index.php*** page which serves login page for my application in chrome (or in any browser in general).Can webpack can be used for this ? what other options do I have ?

Comment: Have a look at [phar-files](https://www.php.net/manual/en/phar.creating.intro.php)